# MYSQL - Database backup every transaction

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I'm doing a project where users upload money on the system, after the database queries will increase and decrease this initial amount.
I have to do a backup that allows me, in case the server is broken, to reconstruct the identical situation before the break without losing EVEN ONE TRANSACTION.
Considering that the database does not weigh a few MB, and that will be made 3/4 queries per hour, I think about doing an incremental backup every performed on the database transaction.
Is there a program that when the database is made to a query that modifies data (INSERT, UPDATE), takes a backup ?

Comment: I agree with Julien below.  In addition, if the DB is small and you have access to something like VMWare H/A, you can set it up to do bit-copies of every change.  I have done this in the past.  The only issue with it is that if you have a corruption of some sort, this corruption is replicated directly to the target machine from the source.  Having come off of some very convoluted and extraordinarily painful PCI "stuff", I can say that there isn't much help from their docs.  Master / Slave is probably your best option.

Answer (score 0):

A daily snapshot (using `mysqldump`) on a remote server plus one or many slaves in different geographical location is enough:

- If you loose the master: the slave have up-to-date data
- If you loose some data: The master and the slave store queries in replication binary log
- If you loose everything: You still have the daily backup.

But if you're storing real money in a MySQL table, please consider using cryptographic proofs of the state of the database like by storing a checksum (like a `sha256`) of each transaction salted with the previous one so nobody can `update` a single transaction without updating every checksums of all other after the modified one: `sha256(current_transaction, previous_sha1)`.

You may also document yourself about "write only databases", which is what signing rows forces you to do : deleting a raw destruct the sha1 chain, marking the table as obviously tempered.

Can't write enough in a single response about each and every security measure you can take while storing money, but obviously backup is not enough (they can be modified too (sha256 "proofs" in each lines of each backups can be altered too...).

But you may document yourself in the direction of certifications like the "Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard" (PCI DSS) which probably contains a lot of information about what you're trying to achieve.